# jquery gwt checkbox

Tags: jquery, gwt, checkbox

how can i implement jquery expression `if($("[name='abc']:checked").length > 1)` in GWT??

Comment: now i am using gwtquery 
http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted
how can i write expression using gwtquery for the above expression

Comment: Hey msaif, please don't create a new account each time you need to ask a question on SO. Your reputation lets people know it's worth their time to help answer your question, and starting over each time means fewer good answers for you in the future. http://www.google.com/search?q=msaif+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do this would be by using JSNI (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html). In other words you could write pure javascript functions, include jquery lib (one way would be to include jquery in your html page), and you would be able to use jquery expressions in those native functions.

The other alternative is GWT query which is basically a wrapper around jquery so that jquery functions can be called from GWT java code.

One other think I would like to mention is that, if I were you, I would go with only things that GWT provides. GWT compiler produces small, obfuscated and optimized js and I don't believe that introducing one more library would give you an output better then that.